# Expose Pulsar broker with Kubernetes Ingress

Tags: ssl, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, apache-pulsar

I deployed pulsar using helm without activating tls.
Now I want to expose it using a nginx ingress, without tls in a first time. It does not work, I get this on client side:

```
Got exception TooLongFrameException : Adjusted frame length exceeds 5253120: 1213486164 - discarded
```

Is missing specific annotations?

In a second time, I want to expose it in secure way using a ssl certificate. Does ingress work with pulsar+ssl protocol? Should I need specific annotation also?

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: pulsar
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: pulsar.myurl.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: pulsar-proxy
          servicePort: 6650
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - pulsar.myurl.com
    secretName: pulsar.myurl.com.crt
```

Answer (score 5):

Kubernetes ingress is for HTTP traffic. The Pulsar protocol (port 6650) is a binary protocol, not HTTP. You need to expose it using a TCP LoadBalancer service (for example, Network Load Balancer in AWS).

If you are running multiple Pulsar brokers, you should use the Pulsar proxy for external connectivity, because the Pulsar handshake assumes the client can connect to the individual brokers. The Pulsar proxy handles this complexity for you. For more details on the Pulsar proxy, see this [page](https://github.com/apache/pulsar/wiki/PIP-1:-Pulsar-Proxy). You will still need to use a TCP LoadBalancer service to expose the proxy.

Comment: What do you think about https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services ? I don't understand if it enable nginx to act like a LB or if an external LB is needed? Same question about Treaffik?

Comment: Even if you can configure the Nginx ingress to proxy the TCP port, you will still have a problem if you have multiple brokers. But if you are using just one broker, it could work since it looks like it is just modifying the LoadBalancer service associated with the Nginx ingress.

Comment: I have only one broker behind pulsar-proxy. But when I create the "TCP load balancing" following previous link, ingress remains in pending state. I'm a little confused, I don't know if this enables nginx to expose TCP directly or if LB is still necessary.

Comment: Isn't it possible to expose the Pulsar proxy (port 6650) through the Kubernetes Ingress Loadbalancer instead of the broker directly? In that way you can expose more than one broker through the proxy over the K8s Ingress outward. In this way, implementations like Kind (Kubernetes-in-Docker) can be used to simulate a multi node K8S cluster with multiple brokers on a local host, without the requirement for a cloud provider (AWS, etc).

Comment: I try to expose pulsar-proxy. My issue is that I don't have a Load Balancer (because i'm on prem) and I don't manage to set up nginx "TCP load balancing" ingress.